# I am facing an issue with Redux framework and qTranslate X

Tags: multilingual, qtranslate, redux-framework

I am used to `qTranslate X` for multilingual WP site. But, I am facing a problem with `Redux framework` (for theme option) and `qTranslate X`. I found all `language switcher button` in theme option. But, when I put individual value for each language, then this field taken only last value for all languages.Is it possible to use `Redux framework` with `qTranslate X`? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Did the problem solve?